# Python script to convert asn to .hpp

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a script that turns an asn file into a hpp file, but it look very dirty even though I have made changes based on pylint.

I think I make use of too many lists, for-loops and try except blocks.

I would like to get a review of my code, and I am particularly interested in making my code look more organized and make my code more efficient.

> Sample input
>
> ```
> SerError ::= CHO
> {
>    app-ref [0] IMPLICIT ENUMERATED
>    {
>       --  provider only
>       other (0),
>       ti-ela (1)
>
>
>    },
>    ha-res [1] IMPLICIT ENUMERATED
>    {
>       --  hardware 
>       other (0),
>       me-unavailable (1)
>
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Sample output
>
> ```
> enum ESererror//SSerError ::= CHO
> {
>    eSererrorAppRef = 0, 
>    eSererrorHaRes = 1
> };
>
> enum EAppRef//pp-ref [0] IMPLICIT ENUMERATED
> {
>    //--  provider only
>    eAppRefOther = 0,
>    eAppRefTiEla = 1
> };
>
> enum EHaRes//ha-res [1] IMPLICIT ENUMERATED
> {
>    //-- VDE hardware troubles
>    eHaResOther = 0,
>    eHaResMeUnavailable = 1
> };
> ```

This is the script I would like to have reviewed:

```
'''
************************************************************************

@brief 
@version 1.0

************************************************************************
'''
import re
from collections import deque
import sys
import inflection


class Convert(object):
    '''To do: add data'''
    def __init__(self):
        '''To do: add data'''
        self.plist = []
        self.slist = []
        self.tlist = []
        self.llist = []
        self.lines = []
        self.line = None
        self.open_braces = []
        self.close_braces = []
        self.outputfile = None
        self.i = None
        self.open_brace_list = []
        self.close_brace_list = []
        self.file_name = None
        self.split_character = None
        self.length = None
        self.enumvariable_flag = None
        self.inner_variable_prefix=""

    def start_tag(self, split_character, line):
        '''To do: add data'''
        self.split_character = split_character
        self.line = line
        line_to_write = ""
        line_to_write += "enum E"
        self.inner_variable_prefix = (inflection.camelize(((self.line.split(self.split_character)[0]).replace('-', '_')).lower())).strip()
        line_to_write += self.inner_variable_prefix
        line_to_write += "//"+self.line
        line_to_write += "\n"
        line_to_write += "{\n"
        self.outputfile.write(line_to_write)
        self.enumvariable_flag = True

    def end_tag(self,line):
        self.line=line
        line_to_write = ""
        line_to_write += "};\n"
        self.outputfile.write(line_to_write)
        self.enumvariable_flag = False

    def comment_line(self, line):
        self.line = line
        line_to_write = ""
        line_to_write += "//"+self.line+"\n"
        self.outputfile.write(line_to_write)
    def handle_comment(self, line):
        '''To do: add data'''
        self.line = line
        if (line.strip()).startswith("--")or(re.search(r'(.*)\{(.*)\}(.*)', line)):
            line_to_write = "   "
            line_to_write += "//"+self.line+"\n"
            self.outputfile.write(line_to_write)

    def handle_inner_element(self, line, index):
        '''To do: add data'''
        self.line = line
        self.index = index
        line_to_write = "   "
        try:
            try:
                value = (re.findall(r'\d+', self.line.strip().split(' ')[1])[0])
                line_to_write += "e"
                line_to_write += self.inner_variable_prefix
                line_to_write += inflection.camelize((self.line.strip().split(' ')[0]).replace('-', '_'))
                line_to_write += " = "
                line_to_write += value
                if self.index not in self.llist:
                    line_to_write += ","
                line_to_write += "\n"
            except:
                if (self.line.strip().split(' ')[0]).lower() == \
                   self.line.strip().split(' ')[1].split('-')[0].lower():
                    line_to_write += "e"
                    line_to_write += self.inner_variable_prefix
                    line_to_write += inflection.camelize((
                        self.line.strip().split(' ')[0].replace('-', '_')).lower())
                    if self.index not in self.llist:
                        line_to_write += ","
                else:
                    line_to_write += "//"
                    line_to_write += self.line
                line_to_write += "\n"
        except Exception as exception:
            print(exception)
        self.outputfile.write(line_to_write)

    def generate_lists(self, length, lines):
        '''To do: add data'''
        self.length = length
        self.lines = lines
        flag_llist=False
        lastl=None
        for index, line in enumerate(self.lines):
            reg1 = r'::=(.*)\n\{'

            reg2 = r'{'

            reg3 = r'\}'

            reg4 = r'(.*)\{(.*)\}(.*)'
            if index < (self.length-1):
                val = str(line) + "\n" + str(self.lines[index+1])
            else:
                val = str(line)
            if re.search(reg1, val)and(not re.search(reg4, val)):
                self.plist.append(index)
                flag_llist=True
            else:
                val = str(line)
            if re.search(reg2, val)and(not re.search(reg4, val)):
                if index in self.plist:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.slist.append(index)
                    flag_llist=True
            if re.search(reg3, val)and(not re.search(reg4, val)):
                self.tlist.append(index)
                self.llist.append(lastl)
                flag_llist=False
            elif flag_llist:
                try:
                    value = (re.findall(r'\d+', line.strip().split(' ')[1])[0])
                    lastl=index
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    if (line.strip().split(' ')[0]).lower() == \
                       line.strip().split(' ')[1].split('-')[0].lower():
                        lastl=index
                except:
                    pass

        return self.plist, self.slist, self.tlist

    def add_sub_element(self, open_brace_list, close_brace_list):
        '''To do: add data'''
        self.open_brace_list = open_brace_list
        self.close_brace_list = close_brace_list
        line_to_write = ""
        self.enumvariable_flag = False
        for i in range(1, len(self.open_brace_list)):
            for index, line in enumerate(self.lines):
                if index == self.open_brace_list[i]-1:
                    self.start_tag(' ', line)
                if (index <= self.close_brace_list[i-1])and\
                   (index > self.open_brace_list[i])and self.enumvariable_flag:
                    self.handle_comment(line)
                    if (self.line.strip()).startswith("}"):
                        self.end_tag(line)
                if self.enumvariable_flag and(not (self.line.strip()).startswith("--"))and\
                   (not (self.line.strip()).startswith("{")and\
                    (index <= self.close_brace_list[i-1])and(index > open_brace_list[i])):
                    self.handle_inner_element(line, index)

    def braces_line_no(self, i):
        '''To do: add data'''
        self.i = i
        remaining_slist = [a for a in self.slist if a > self.plist[self.i]]
        remaining_tlist = [a for a in self.tlist if a > self.plist[self.i]]
        try:
            self.open_braces = [b for b in remaining_slist if b < self.plist[self.i+1]]
        except:
            self.open_braces = remaining_slist
        try:
            self.close_braces = [b for b in remaining_tlist if b < self.plist[self.i+1]]
        except:
            self.close_braces = remaining_tlist
        return self.open_braces, self.close_braces

    def generate_output(self, file_name):
        '''To do: add data'''
        self.file_name = file_name
        output_file_name = self.file_name.split('.')[0]+".hpp"
        self.outputfile = open(output_file_name, 'w')
        with open(self.file_name) as f_in:
            self.lines = (line.strip() for line in f_in)
            self.lines = list(line for line in self.lines if line)
        length = len(self.lines)
        self.plist, self.slist, self.tlist = self.generate_lists(length, self.lines)
        for i in range(len(self.plist)):
            line_to_write = ""
            self.open_braces, self.close_braces = self.braces_line_no(i)
            open_braces_qu = deque(self.open_braces)
            for index, line in enumerate(self.lines):
                if (not self.enumvariable_flag)and(self.tlist[-1] != self.close_braces[-1]):
                    if(index > self.close_braces[-1]) and (index < self.slist[self.slist.index(self.open_braces[-1])+1]-1):
                            self.comment_line(line)
                    elif self.enumvariable_flag==None and (index < self.plist[0]):
                        self.comment_line(line)
                elif self.close_braces[-1] == self.tlist[-1] and index > self.tlist[-1]:
                    self.comment_line(line)
                if index == self.plist[i]:
                    self.start_tag('::=', line)
                elif len(self.open_braces) == 1 and len(self.close_braces) == 1 and\
                     self.enumvariable_flag:
                    self.handle_comment(line)
                    if (self.line.strip()).startswith("}"):
                        self.end_tag(line)
                    if self.enumvariable_flag and(not (line.strip()).startswith("--"))and\
                       (not (line.strip()).startswith("{")):
                        self.handle_inner_element(line, index)

                elif self.enumvariable_flag and(len(self.open_braces) > 1)and(len(open_braces_qu) > 1):
                    line_to_write = "   "
                    try:
                        if index == open_braces_qu[1]-1:
                            try:
                                value = (re.findall(r'\d+', line.strip().split(' ')[1])[0])
                                line_to_write += "e"
                                line_to_write += self.inner_variable_prefix
                                line_to_write += inflection.camelize((line.strip().split(' ')[0]\
                                                                      .replace('-', '_')).lower())
                                line_to_write += " = "
                                line_to_write += value
                                if len(open_braces_qu) > 2:
                                    line_to_write += ", "
                                line_to_write += "\n"
                            except:
                                if (line.strip().split(' ')[0]).lower() == line.strip()\
                                   .split(' ')[1].split('-')[0].lower():
                                    line_to_write += "e"
                                    line_to_write += self.inner_variable_prefix
                                    line_to_write += inflection.camelize((line.strip()\
                                    .split(' ')[0].replace('-', '_')).lower())
                                    if len(open_braces_qu) > 2:
                                        line_to_write += ", "
                                else:
                                    line_to_write += "//"
                                    line_to_write += line
                                line_to_write += "\n"
                            self.outputfile.write(line_to_write)
                            open_braces_qu.popleft()
                            if  len(open_braces_qu) == 1:
                                self.end_tag(line)
                                open_braces_qu.popleft()
                                self.add_sub_element(self.open_braces, self.close_braces)

                    except Exception as exception:
                        print(exception)

        self.outputfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    INPUT_FILE_NAME = sys.argv[1]
    CON_OBJ = Convert()
    CON_OBJ.generate_output(INPUT_FILE_NAME)
```

Comment: It would help if you could summarize what the script is for and change the title to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 5):

You should also *never* have a bare `except`. Always use at least `except Exception`. Because otherwise you can't e.g. abort with CTRL-C anymore if it is stuck.

You should also try to limit their scope as small as possible to guard only the one operation which may fail. Otherwise it becomes a lot harder to debug as well.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, strings are not mutable. What this means is that every time you do `line_to_write += "foo_barred"` a new string will be created which is a concatenated version of the two strings, and the new string will then be stored into `line_to_print`.

This may not seem very bad, but it can sneak up on you in a couple different ways:

1. Short strings being concatenated in **most** cases *can* be faster. However, using concatenation on large strings **and** in a loop will result in poor performance.
2. Strings being immutable necessarily means that when doing large amounts of manipulations on strings (**esp** short ones). Large amounts of new strings are being created, returned, maybe even cleaned up depending on how the interpreter is feeling today.

Regardless of whether the memory is being cleared properly however, this is likely to create large amounts of memory fragmentation due to constant alloc / dealloc / realloc... The smaller the strings and the faster you run, the more memory will get fragmented.

Ideally you should be doing less nesting of control flow. I generally try to keep anything deeper than ~3 control flow structures in a separate method since it will be easier to understand and maintain that way.

Comment: should I use data type such as **list** instead of string concatenation _line_to_write_ to avoid fragmentation

Comment: i have update my script with list...but the execution time has increased multi folds. so it that okay ? `old script  took 0.019999980926513672 seconds.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
new script took 0.2999999523162842 seconds. `

Comment: only if you are working with the same long string alot will it become __much__ of an issue, all optimization comes down to 3 steps, Test how fast it runs(and where the time is coming from), Make modifications to the slowest bits, Retest and revert any Performance regressions.

Answer (score 3):

- The `outputfile` should be protected with `with open(...) as ...` as well, just assign it to `self.outputfile` in that block.
- `reg1` to `reg3` are only used once, perhaps just inline them.
- `brace_lines` has duplicated code, I'd try to split it so that you can just pass in the two lists to a shared method/function.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to look "clean" you can try reducing the line count. Reduce `if` blocks to comprehensions:

```
if index < (self.length-1):
    val = str(line) + "\n" + str(self.lines[index+1])
else:
    val = str(line)
```

to:

```
val = str(line) + "\n" + str(self.lines[index+1]) if index < (self.length-1) else str(line)
```

reduce `+=` calls

```
    line_to_write += self.inner_variable_prefix
    line_to_write += "//"+self.line
    line_to_write += "\n"
    line_to_write += "{\n"
```

to:

```
    line_to_write += self.inner_variable_prefix+"//"+self.line+"\n"+"{\n"
```

use less self variables `self.i`, its never used globally, only in `braces_line_no()`

When things are shorter you might be able to notice some improvements you can make to your control structure, as well as decrease the amount of lines you have which will make it easier to catch mistakes and view all your code.